# pandas dataframe enforce monotically per row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe:

```
df = 0 1 2 3 4 
     1 1 3 2 5
     4 1 5 7 8
     7 1 2 3 9
```

I want to enforce monotonically per row, to get:

```
df = 0 1 2 3 4 
     1 1 3 3 5
     4 4 5 7 8
     7 7 7 7 9
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 3):

Try `cummax`

```
out = df.cummax(1)
Out[80]: 
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  3  3  5
1  4  4  5  7  8
2  7  7  7  7  9
```